# Using for loop for summation in R

Tags: r, math

This is probably extremely obvious but I've been trying without success to fix it for about an hour (I'm kinda a beginner):

The function is a sum from 1:8 of the expression: xi*yi - 284400(i) where xi and yi are from a data frame with two columns X and Y both of length 8. I'm just trying to find the numerical value without having to calculate it myself.

I tried the following code, but when using the for loop it seems to keep assigning i an integer value of 8. Am I using the for loop incorrectly?

Note: I made a vector of the x column called 'xvalues' and similarly the y column was called 'yvalues'

```
for(i in 1:8){
    sum((xvalues[i]*yvalues[i])-284400*(i))
    }
```

After running this I keep getting a null output and when I call i, it just gives:

```
[1] 8
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sum(xvalues * yvalues - 284400*(1:8))` ... without a loop.

Comment: Hello. Do you want to get the sum of this product for each value-pair `xvalues`/`yvalues` or the total sum of all operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely because you aren't storing your result of intermediate a steps so you only get the result of the final calculation.

You can get the total sum (using a loop) with:

```
# Initialize variable with the sum 
my.sum = 0
for(i in 1:8){
    current = (xvalues[i]*yvalues[i])-284400*(i)
    # Update variable storing sum
    my.sum = my.sum + current
}
> my.sum
```

Alternatively, you can vectorize the calculation using:

```
i = 1:8
sum((xvalues[i]*yvalues[i])-284400*(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `sum(df$X * df$Y - 284400*(1:nrow(df)))`

Or you can use `dplyr` for that:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(value = X * Y - 284400 * row_number()) %>%
  summarise(sumvalue = sum(value))
```